# How can I set proofing language to a language different than my keyboard layout in Word 2016?

Tags: ms-word, keyboard, spell-checking

Well, I'm writing a Word document in French and want the proofing/spelling language to be the French but I actually wanna type using the English keyboard layout, so when I try to use the english keyboard layout the proofing/spelling language also becomes English!! How can I fix that?

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions.

Answer (score 0):

I think this the wrong site, if someone could move it to the right one it would be beneficial. Anyway, I figured out the solution which is to add a language to the computer (Proofing language) and inside this language add the input layout that you want.